# How to use AJAX on MVC in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, model-view-controller

I am making a cart system and what I am trying to do is that when the button "add to cart" is clicked, it send automatically the data to the cart table. The problem I am facing now is that when data is sent to the cart table I still need to refresh the page before I can see it which I don't want, I want to see the data inserted immediately on the the view. Please i am desperately in need of help

**ajax**

```
    $('#product-form').submit(function(e){
        alert("Data sent successfully");
        e.preventDefault();
        var product = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/ibuy_e-commerce/product/',
            data: product,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                if(response.error){
                    alert("Data sent in");
                }
                else{
                getCart();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
getCart();
function getCart(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/ibuy_e-commerce/product/?action=getCart',
        success: function(response){
            $('#cart_menu').html(response.cartId);
            $('.cart_count').html(response.cartId);
        }
    });
}
```

**controller**

```
case 'getCart':
    // Get the userId on session
    $userData = getFromSession('userData');
    // Fetch the items in cart from the DB on session
    $proCartArray= getCart($userData->user_id);
    // Convert the array to a JSON object and send it back
    echo json_encode($proCartArray);
    break;
```

**View**

```
<form id="product-form" class="form-horizontal"> 
<input type='text' name='quantity' value='1' min="1" class='input-number' />  
<button type="submit" >add to cart</button>  
</form"> 
<ul class="menu" id="cart_menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/ibuy_e-commerce/product/?action=product-details&id=<?= $cart['product_id'] ?>">
                            <div class="cart-img-container">
                                <img src="<?= $cart['imgPath'] ?>" alt=" Image de <?= $cart['product_model'] ?>">
                            </div>
                            <h4 class="cart-prodName">
                                <a href="/ibuy_e-commerce/product/?action=product-details&id=<?= $cart['product_id'] ?>"><b><?= $cart['product_model'] ?></b></a>
                                <small>× <?= $cart['qty'] ?></small>
                                <span class="cart-prod-color txt-grey"><?= $cart['product_color'] ?></span>
                            </h4>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
```

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, from what you wrote, it's not clear what you want to achieve. Try to rephrase the second phrase.

Comment: From what I can work out, you've shown us your HTML "add to cart" form and some AJAX to handle that, including a `getCart()` function to do something when the AJAX is done - presumably get the newly updated cart contents and update the page to show it.  So what's the problem, doesn't it work?  Some errors?  Not behaving as you expected? 
 Please edit your question and add details.

Answer (score 0):

try to debug at function getCart() after sending data to server.
If code run that function, you can edit this lines

```
$('#cart_menu').html(response.cartId);
$('.cart_count').html(response.cartId);
```

div with id #cart_menu is set content equal response.cartId, every child of it will be replace by a plain text with cartID